# change java version in macOS BigSur

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-home

I can't change the java version in macOS BigSur.
i have the following versions :

when I execute this command

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

i have the following versions :

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    11.0.8 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.261.12 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_261 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

i want to switch to java 1.8 as the default one , so I execute this command :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_261
```

and then when I check java version :

```
java -version
```

I still got the old (higher one)

```
java version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

why it's not working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please use below command :-

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_261`
```

Comment: it's not working , I still have java 11 as java version

Comment: @leonidas79 after you run that command, then run `set | grep JAVA` what does it show you?

Comment: The purposes of the backticks means that the command runs and then puts it output into the variable `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: When I run set | grep JAVA , I get this : JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/home

Comment: Thanks ! Worked.
I was facing issue with /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

This home was set to default but I wanted to use JDK 1.8, java -version was showing 1.8 but still not able to find 1.8 sun tools.

Above command set home properly and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

you have to unset JAVA_HOME and set JAVA_VERSION
then it works.

```
~% JAVA_VERSION=12 java -version
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
~% export JAVA_VERSION=12
~% java -version
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
~% unset JAVA_HOME
~% java -version
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
~% JAVA_VERSION=13 java -version
java version "13-ea" 2019-09-17
```

or if you need to set JAVA_HOME you need to unset before calling `/usr/libexec/java_home`

```
function jav {
unset JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
}
~% jav 12
~% java -version
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
~% jav 13
~% java -version
java version "13-ea" 2019-09-17
```

Comment: "unset JAVA_HOME" : Unsetting JAVA_HOME really did the trick for me, even when "set | grep JAVA" shows JAVA_HOME=' ':

Answer (score 8):

Now there's new binary at `/usr/bin/java` and it gets prioritized over `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`

Comment: Fixed by: `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`, making binary from JAVA_HOME in front of `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: Yes, where does this come from and how do we modify this?

Comment: this PATH is exported either in `~/.bash_profile` or your other shell config file, eg. `~/.zshrc` for zShell. You may need to do `source ~/.bash_profile`, or just open new terminal window after that

Answer (score 6):

I have added following on my .zshenv and it's working fine. Thanks munan.

```
## Java home 
export JAVA_8_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
export JAVA_11_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
export JAVA_17_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v17)

## Java alias
alias java8="export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME"
alias java11="export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_11_HOME"
alias java17="export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_17_HOME"
alias jv='java -version'

## Default Java
java11
```

To change the java version from console, use: java8, java11 or java17

Answer (score 5):

I have been confused with the same issue today after upgrade macOS to Big Sur.

There are two JDKs on my Mac, Oracle JDK 11 and Oracle JDK 8.

Then `/usr/libexec/java_home` always return `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` and ignore other arguments like `-v 1.8`

After some tests I found that, this only happened when your Mac have an Oracle JDK 1.8.X version.

So I deleted the Oracle JDK 1.8.x, `/usr/libexec/java_home` can return the correct JDK 11 path.

Then I tried AdoptOpenJDK 8, `/usr/libexec/java_home` can return its path correctly, but ignore the `-v 11` arg, can't get the path of JDK 11.

It seems there ARE some bugs in `java_home` command, if you only have one JDK on your Mac - except Oracle JDK 8- it should works fine. If you have multiple
JDKs, maybe it just return the last installed JDK path.

So either only keep one JDK installation or set `$JAVA_HOME` env with the absolute path will be OK.

Answer (score 4):

in my opinion the command `"/usr/libexec/java_home -v"` doesn't work. I solved exporting directly the java path in file .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and then doing the command:

```
source .bash_profile.
```

After this using the command:
echo $JAVA_HOME I've seen that the JVM path is set correctly.

Comment: This is odd.  On our build machine I did not have this.  On my local machine I also did not have this but don't have the Android Gradle build issue either.  Added this on the build machine and it works just fine now.  Not sure why it is not needed on my local laptop

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATE: Mac OS 13.1

When you install an openjdk version (in addition to the system/default installed), for example:

```bash
brew install openjdk@11
```

(in my case, at least) it is not linked to the right location by default. You need to symlink it as outlined [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2405#discussioncomment-1593871)

```bash
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
```

This way when you run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, you will see all the installed versions

```bash
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    19.0.1 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 19.0.1" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.18 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 11.0.18" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.18/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And choosing the right one is as simple as setting the env variable `$JAVA_HOME`

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`  # to set to java 11, for eg
```

Running `java --version` confirms:

```
openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.18+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.18+0, mixed mode)
```

Comment: if its not working, try export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12`

Answer (score 2):

For those who have tried all these answers and is still stuck, I did use a SDKMAN and their init script was forcing somehow Java to be on version 1.8.

Since their scripts were at the end of my `~/.zshrc`, it didn't matter how many times I ran the correct commands, `java -version` always came out as 1.8.

What i did was ignore SDKMAN warning on  `~/zshrc` file and put `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"` at the end of file and worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I followed following steps to fix an issue to set java version I needed in macOS BigSur. :

when I execute this command

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

I was having the following versions :

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
17 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 17" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
11.0.17.0-m1 (x86_64) "IBM Corporation" - "IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 11" /Users/airasia/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/semeru-11.0.17/Contents/Home
1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

Then, I wanted to switched to java 1.8 as the default one , so I executed this command :

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)' >> ~/.profile
```

and then when I checked java version :

```
java --version
```

I was still getting the old (higher one)

```
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

`~/.profile` file was looking like,

```
vim ~/.profile
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I checked

```
set | grep JAVA         
JAVA_HOME=JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then I added new `JAVA_HOME` in `~/.profile` file,

```
vim ~/.profile
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And executed it,

```
source ~/.profile
```

Now java pointing to `1.8.0_292`,

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

To fallback to `openjdk 17` again, I will just need to remove one line,

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

And add,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin
```

And executed it,

```
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too,So annoying,  he caused me trouble.
He seems to be solved by set the '$JAVA_VERSION'.
Please use below command :-

```
export JAVA_VERSION=11
```

Comment: Works perfectly